# How to read Large number of SMSs by Java program?

Tags: java, sms, gsm, modem, at-command

I want to receive/read large number of SMSs via Java program. Will AT commands help me?
Here I may have to read 10,000 SMS per minute (also have to delete them as well).

As I heard we should add some delay between AT commands (thread.sleep).

Comment: Are you sure another protocol might not be better?  I suspect if you send 10,000 messages per minute to a device, it won't cope so well.  Have you considered an Android phone to program and receive SMS.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt a single GSM modem can receive that huge amount of SMS, based only on my opinion. AT commands will help you to interface the hardware to the JAVA program. http://www.smslib.org maybe a good start for you. Let's exercice how many messages you can read per minute on a regular GSM modem. Given the response time for each AT command is usually 50ms and you need 2 AT commands to read a message. (To list the messages and to read the message at index provided at the list command). At the optimal setting, you can read 6000 messages per minute. When you receive a message your phone gets unresponsive too, but I never measured for how long. lets say it's 100ms too. Your phone can receive 3000 messages per minute, if you start deleting them, also will reduce your reading speed. I don't think a single modem can handle such requirement. My numbers are just to illustrate my point, they vary depending on the hardware used. If you really need use SMS, I'd recommend using a gateway service enables you to receive SMS.

Answer (score 1):

A GSM device is not a suitable way to receive so many SMSs.

To add to André's post, the gateway server that you need to use is connected directly to the SMSC (Short Message Service Centre) in the network.  These servers use a protocol like SMPP to deliver and send large numbers of SMSs over a wired connection with the SMSC.
You should be able to rent space on such a gatway server.